# Create shortcut for directory on Mac

Tags: bash, terminal

I have the directory `dir one` which I need to create a shortcut for. 
It will show up in the finder as a clickable file.

```
#!/bin/bash  
ln -s "/Users/tcokimac/Documents/dir one" "/Users/tcokimac/Desktop/"
```

I am getting

```
zsh: permission denied
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post and include the complete command you ran and the complete, unabbreviated output?

Comment: This is the completed command

Comment: You have posted a script and half an error message. Please post the command you used to run the script and the complete error message